# php upload script produces error 500 for files larger than 100 Kb

Tags: php, file-upload

I have the following php script

```
<?php


  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }

?>
```

can anyone help allow it to upload pdf files larger than around 100 Kb?

I have checked with my hosting provider and everything is correct there, I have also checked phpinfo() which states that uploads to 8 Mb should be allowed

Can anyone help point me in the right direction to fix this, my hosting provider suggested I create a php.ini file, but want commands does it need to contain to allow uploading?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you only need to upload pdf ?

Comment: Thanks for everyones help the actual error I was getting was mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 136480 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072) see http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2-mod_fcgid-http-request-length-exceeds-maxrequestlen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a small tips for you which you can use to upload such a large file using file field of the form and move_uploaded_file() function in PHP.

1) Create a .htaccess file in the root folder of web server.

2) Put the following code in side the .htaccess file and save it.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 8M
php_value post_max_size 8M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Now you can upload the file-size up-to 8MB in a simple way using file field in your html form and move_uploaded_file() function available in PHP.

Comment: Agreed, but play with times it should be the last resource (3 minutes+ is too much!). First it could be better to depurate the script.

Answer (score 2):

For 1Mb.

In your local php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 1M
post_max_size = 1M
```

If not works, add to your .htaccess file in the root directory.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1M
php_value post_max_size 1M
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Query Master's response first - this should guarantee the settings are correct. If that doesn't fix it, then, if you get a 500 error, you need check error logs to find out what the problem actually is.

If you can't check error logs then, at the top of your PHP file add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

and that will return the problem to you.

Remember to remove those lines for a live application (you should not reveal errors to the end user as it demonstrates weaknesses that might be exploitable).

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am getting error 500 before the page with the above gets a chance to be shown. Anyone know how to turn error logging on via a htaccess file. I can see the page being accessed in my access log but it gives no details of exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Find those two lines in php.ini and put in exactly the same. Restart Apache, and error reopen in turned on globally. Make sure your app doesn't turn then of :-) . Also revert to safe when done.