# Error code 7 when I'm uploading file to my apache server

Tags: php, apache

```
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");

if ($_FILES['test']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
  echo 'filename: ' . $_FILES['test']['name'] . '<br/>';

  if (file_exists('upload/' . $_FILES['test']['name']))
  {
    echo 'file exist<br/>';
  } 
  else 
  {
    $file = $_FILES['test']['tmp_name'];
    $dest = 'upload/' . $_FILES['test']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($file, $dest);
    echo "seccess";
  }
} 
else 
{
  echo 'error code：' . $_FILES['test']['error'] . '<br/>';
}
```

This is my PHP code, I'm just trying to upload a simple tiny txt file to my apache server.
It worked when I ran it in localhost, but error code 7 when I tried to run  with apache.

```
chmod -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Already set **www-data** as the owner of **www**, disk space is enough to save the file.

Anything I can do to solve error code 7 problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the directory has `writeable` permission. The error says that you don't have permission to save or write in that directory.
Also, check disk space of that directory.

For more details of error code, please see this link: 
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Already change permission of /var/www /var/tmp to 775. Still got the same error code. 
By the way, what is the meaning of disk space of that directory.

Comment: I add ˋUploadException($_FILES['file']['error']);ˋ in my php, and i got HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: please check these php_value upload_max_filesize 8M
php_value post_max_size 8M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721234/php-upload-script-produces-error-500-for-files-larger-than-100-kb

Comment: I already change those value to 1024M and set time to 600 seconds but i still got the same HTTP ERROR 500 while I'm uploading a 9 bytes text file.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: Yes, I restart my apache too.

Comment: Please see solution 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282408/ckeditor-uploadimage-404-error-plugin-setup

Comment: I check the Network tab, i can't find anything like my upload file while i click upload in my html.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to reply. 
After I learned how to check the partition of current directory, I found that my disk space is filled by error.log so that I could't upload anything.
Your first reply is absolute right. Thanks again

Comment: I am glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This could also be your temp file is out of space (just happened to me) - this is where the file goes whilst it is being uploaded.

You can find your tmp file destination in your php.ini file under the following value:

upload_tmp_dir

Normally this will clean itself once the file has finished uploading, but in my case one of my admins copied some videos there for safe keeping whilst making some more space, so the symptoms where that I could upload small files but not large ones, it was quite puzzling at first.

This may also happen if your upload file is larger than your temp space - Although I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post. Although, I solved error 7 by modifying selinux flag:

setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on

I hope that anyone who gets here looking to solve error curl error 7 finds this useful.